# WebAPI routing cuts wildcard parameter on a question mark

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

I have a route in controller that should match everything in part of url and put it into string parameter.

What I have is:

```
    [Route("api/proxy/{proxyId}/{*parameter}")]
    public Task<HttpResponseMessage> Mediate(int proxyId, string parameter)
```

and for an unknown url, for example:

> http://localhost/api/proxy/1/test?a=1&b=2

I would like "parameter" variable to contain:

> test?a=1&b=2

Instead, it contains:

> test

How can I specify route to not cut everything after question mark?
For this particular case I can extract it from Request.RequestUri object, but it would be.. inelegant.

Comment: How about extending your route template like `[Route("api/proxy/{proxyId}/{parameter}/{a}/{b}")]`?

Comment: I don't know what the parameters are going to be

Comment: Perhaps you can find an additional clue [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22642874/query-string-not-working-while-using-attribute-routing)...

Comment: One of the possibilities would be creating a custom Route attribute which would gather parameters from query string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot do that. By definition the URL segments doesn't include the query string.

However, you can do something really easy: inside your WebApi controller you have the `Request` property which contains the Query String:

```
Request.RequestUri.Query
```

You simply have to concatenate the url param with this to have what you need. This includes the leading question mark:

> The Query property contains any query information included in the URI. Query information is separated from the path information by a question mark (?) and continues to the end of the URI. The query information returned includes the leading question mark.

from [Uri.Query Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.query(v=vs.110).aspx)

If you still want to force it to work in a different way, you'd need to include your own custom route provider, implementeing your own [IDirectRouteProvider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.routing.idirectrouteprovider(v=vs.118).aspx)  and registering it. See this: [get a list of attribute route templates asp.net webapi 2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29337064/get-a-list-of-attribute-route-templates-asp-net-webapi-2-2)

But doing something like this is unnatural. Why do things exactly in a different way as the standard way that all other people aunderstand and use?

Comment: Ok, I ended up using Request.RequestUri.Query.