# Get list of all routes (ASP.NET) when `RoutePrefix` or `Route` attributes are not using

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have several route templates like below and a lot of controllers which include several endpoints.

*Project\App_Start\WebApiConfig.cs:*

```cs
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Code omission

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "Template 1",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}/action"
        );
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "Template 2",
            routeTemplate: "api/master/{controller}/{id}/{history}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional, history = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "Default template",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

How can I get a list of all the routes (endpoints) depending on existing Controllers and their methods?

---

I'm expecting to get something like:

```
GET: api/xxx/
PUT: api/xxx/{id}
DELETE: api/xxx/{id}
PUT: api/yyy/{id}
```

and so on.

---

Update #1

I tried Charles' advice, but seems it shows only route templates
[image: Charles' advice]

---

Update #2

I tried [this advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29441892/2039993).

```
diff --git a/Project/App_Start/WebApiConfig.cs b/Project/App_Start/WebApiConfig.cs
index 9b5a05e..6eb376f 100755
--- a/Project/App_Start/WebApiConfig.cs
+++ b/Project/App_Start/WebApiConfig.cs
@@ -1,15 +1,33 @@
 namespace Project
 {
+    public class ObservableDirectRouteProvider : IDirectRouteProvider
+    {
+        public IReadOnlyList<RouteEntry> DirectRoutes { get; private set; }
+
+        public IReadOnlyList<RouteEntry> GetDirectRoutes(HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, IReadOnlyList<HttpActionDescriptor> actionDescriptors, IInlineConstraintResolver constraintResolver)
+        {
+            var defaultDirectRouteProvider = new DefaultDirectRouteProvider();
+            var directRoutes = defaultDirectRouteProvider.GetDirectRoutes(controllerDescriptor, actionDescriptors, constraintResolver);
+            DirectRoutes = DirectRoutes?.Union(directRoutes).ToList() ?? directRoutes;
+            return directRoutes;
+        }
+    }
+
     /// <summary>
     /// コンフィグクラス
     /// </summary>
     public static class WebApiConfig
     {
+        public static ObservableDirectRouteProvider GlobalObservableDirectRouteProvider = new ObservableDirectRouteProvider();

         /// <summary>
         /// コンフィグ登録
@@ -26,7 +44,7 @@ namespace Project
             config.EnableCors(cors);

-            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
+            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes(GlobalObservableDirectRouteProvider)

diff --git a/Project/Global.asax.cs b/Project/Global.asax.cs
index 12bab21..afa6c5d 100644
--- a/Project/Global.asax.cs
+++ b/Project/Global.asax.cs
@@ -24,6 +25,11 @@ namespace Project
         protected void Application_Start()
         {
             GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
+            var registeredRouteList = WebApiConfig.GlobalObservableDirectRouteProvider.DirectRoutes;
+            for (int i = 0; i < registeredRouteList.Count; i++)
+            {
+                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(registeredRouteList[i].Route.RouteTemplate);
+            }
         }
```

I was able to get list of endpoints, but that list don't include all endpoints. 
As I understand that list include endpoints, where there is explicit route attribute, for example:

```cs
[RoutePrefix("api/xxx")]
public class XXXController : ApiController
// OR
[HttpGet]
[Route("{Id}/history")]
public HttpResponseMessage Get([FromUri] int id)
```

But endpoints without attached `RoutePrefix` or `Route` has not included to the list.

Comment: Maybe this will help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28435734/get-list-of-all-routes

Comment: SeM, there is about ASP.NET Core. Does it appropriate to ASP.NET?

Comment: tymtam, I'm sorry there is about ASP.NET Core. Does it appropriate to ASP.NET?

Comment: As i already got downvoted i won't bother posting all the code anymore. But if you want a complete URL map with all the endpoints you have to loop over all methods of all controllers, fetch all methods of type ActionResult and Task<ActionResult>
then use GetCustomAttribute<HttpPostAttribute, HttpPutAttribute, HttpDeleteAttribute> on all the methods to get the HttpMethod.
Use UrlHelper.GenerateUrl to get the Url for each action.

Comment: Searching on duckduckgo with the exact wording of your title yields multiple results. Did you not attempt to search before asking?

Comment: Joelius, of course, first of all I tried to search.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find the way to get list of all routes (ASP.NET) when `RoutePrefix` or `Route` attributes are not using, but following solution has helped me.
*※ I think it's impossible to get proper list of all routes when `RoutePrefix` or `Route` attributes are not using.*

1. Install Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.HelpPage package.
   Tools → NuGet Package Manager → Package Manager Console

   ```sh
   PW> Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.HelpPage
   ```
2. Edit `Application_Start` method of XXXProject\Global.asax.cs as follow.

   ```cs
   protected void Application_Start()
   {
       GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
       AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas(); // ★Add this line
   }
   ```
3. Edit `Register` method of XXXProject\Areas\HelpPage\App_Start\HelpPageConfig.cs as follow.

   ```cs
   public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
   {
       // Uncomment the following to use the documentation from XML documentation file.
       config.SetDocumentationProvider(new XmlDocumentationProvider(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/XmlDocument.xml"))); // ★Uncomment this line
   }
   ```
4. Enable the XML documentation file.
   Solution explorer → Right click on Project → Select Properties → Select Build page
   Input "App_Data/XmlDocument.xml" in textfield.
   [image: XML documentation]

---

Attributes you should use to get proper ASP.NET Web API's help pages.

1. ResponseType

   ```cs
   [ResponseType(typeof(MyObject))]
   public HttpResponseMessage GetMyObject()
   ```
2. RoutePrefix and Route

   ```cs
   [RoutePrefix("api/MyController")]
   public class MyController : ApiController
   ```

   ```cs
   [Route("MyObject")]
   public HttpResponseMessage GetMyObject()
   ```
3. FromUri and FromBody (optional)

   ```cs
   public HttpResponseMessage PutMyObject([FromUri] int id, [FromBody] MyObject myObject)
   ```

---

To convert ASP.NET Web API's help pages to static html, you can use wget.
For example,

```sh
wget -r -k -E http://<ip_address>/Help/
```

---

Reference:

- [Creating Help Pages for ASP.NET Web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/creating-api-help-pages)
- [Create a REST API with Attribute Routing in ASP.NET Web API 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/create-a-rest-api-with-attribute-routing)

Answer (score -1):

**List routes using ActionDescriptor WITH http method (get,post etc)**

```cs
[Route("")]
[ApiController]
public class RootController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IActionDescriptorCollectionProvider _actionDescriptorCollectionProvider;

    public RootController(IActionDescriptorCollectionProvider actionDescriptorCollectionProvider)
    {
        _actionDescriptorCollectionProvider = actionDescriptorCollectionProvider;
    }

    public RootResultModel Get()
    {
        var routes = _actionDescriptorCollectionProvider.ActionDescriptors.Items.Where(
            ad => ad.AttributeRouteInfo != null).Select(ad => new RouteModel
        {
            Name = ad.AttributeRouteInfo.Template,
            Method = ad.ActionConstraints?.OfType<HttpMethodActionConstraint>().FirstOrDefault()?.HttpMethods.First(),
            }).ToList();

        var res = new RootResultModel
        {
            Routes = routes
        };

        return res;
    }
}
```

Comment: Error CS0246 The type or namespace name 'IActionDescriptorCollectionProvider', 'IActionDescriptorCollectionProvider', 'RootResultModel', 'RouteModel', 'HttpMethodActionConstraint', 'RootResultModel'

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65081126/12154974) could help: a simple code snippet that you can add to the *Configure* method in the *Startup* class, that supposedly retrieve (at least in ASP.NET 3.1) the registered routes